# Why does Git in Cygwin complain about info/refs not being found?

Tags: version-control

I am learning to use git with Drupal. I'm using Cywgin (Windows-based Linux command line), and trying to follow [Practicing patches](http://drupal.org/node/1134754). The documentation tells me to use the command:

```
git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/project/current_content.git
```

However, I appear to have an old version of Git, because it tells me that "--branch" is unknown. The [Git troubleshoot page](http://drupal.org/node/1065850) explains a work around:

```
git clone [project_url] [directory]
cd [directory]
git checkout --track origin/[existing_branch_name] -b [tracking_branch_name]
```

However, the first line tells me:

```
fatal: http://git.drupal.org/project/current_posts/current_posts.git/info/refs
 not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? I've got the last version of git via Cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error, it looks like your `git clone` line was incorrect (it complains about `current_posts`—which isn't a project—instead of `current_content`—which is). Try:

```sh
git clone http://git.drupal.org/project/current_content.git
```

You can also do:

```sh
git clone git@git.drupal.org:/project/current_content.git
```

Note that the `master` branch is the default branch: you don't need to specify it in the clone or afterwards: it'll automatically check it out.